# How to enable JMS provider status in Actuator /health

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I am using Springboot 1.5.12 version and would like to show the JMS Conn. Factory/ providers health status on actuator's /health endpoint. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The health information is collected from all beans implementing `HealthIndicator` interface

So, if the JMS integration doesn't provide any integration with the actuator, you should implement your own HealthIndicator that will query for JMS availability and report on status.

Here is an example:

```
@Component
public class JMSHealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

  @Override
  public Health health() {
    int errorCode = checkJmsAvailability();
    if (errorCode != 0) {
        return Health.down()
           .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
    }
    return Health.up().build();
  }

  public int checkJmsAvailability() {
    // Our logic to check health
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added some more info. Can you please take a look at it ?

Comment: If you have many connection factories, you should first of all decide what to monitor, maybe one health indication per factory? Or maybe 1 health check for all factories (in this case you might to inject a list of beans of those factories or something). If at least one jms connection doesn't work, should you report "up" or not? Its a logic for you to implement...